# How can I convert wordpress feed to XMLHttpRequest

Tags: jquery, wordpress, xmlhttprequest

Is there a way to convert wordpress feeds to XMLHttpRequest so that I can parse the data to show ?

in short: I have a subdomain like  http://sub.main.com which is using wordpress and I want to read the feed from that subdomain (http://sub.main.com/feed/) from my main domain.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Better off using [wordpress REST](http://v2.wp-api.org/) and make sure you implement CORS due to different origin due to sub domain. Beyond that ths question is far too broad for Stackoverflow

Comment: Yea I know its broad but I couldnt find my answer so pls dont judge me, I just need to read the data wp feed provides

Comment: And you can also get that using REST .. either plugin or built in depending on wordpress version